# DependencyPropertyListener() for WPF

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I would like to operate a project planned for windows phone to be used in WPF. 
Here is the link :
[Loading Data when the User Scrolls to the End](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/228873/Loading-Data-when-the-User-Scrolls-to-the-End-of)

By repeating the code , I perceived, that WPF does not know **DependencyPropertyListener()** in this method :

```
 static void element_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    element.Loaded -= element_Loaded;
    ScrollViewer scrollViewer = FindChildOfType<ScrollViewer>(element);
    if (scrollViewer == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("ScrollViewer not found.");
    }

    var listener = new DependencyPropertyListener();
    listener.Changed
        += delegate
        {
            bool atBottom = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset
                                >= scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight;

            if (atBottom)
            {
                var atEnd = GetAtEndCommand(element);
                if (atEnd != null)
                {
                    atEnd.Execute(null);
                }                    
            }
        };
    Binding binding = new Binding("VerticalOffset") { Source = scrollViewer };
    listener.Attach(scrollViewer, binding);
}
```

Would there be a way around this object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to dependency property value change using a `DependencyPropertyDescriptor`.

```
static void element_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    element.Loaded -= element_Loaded;
    ScrollViewer scrollViewer = FindChildOfType<ScrollViewer>(element);
    if (scrollViewer == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("ScrollViewer not found.");
    }

    var dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ScrollViewer.VerticalOffsetProperty, typeof(ScrollViewer));
    dpd.AddValueChanged(scrollViewer, delegate(object o, EventArgs args)
    {
        bool atBottom = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset
                       >= scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight;
        if (atBottom)
        {
            var atEnd = GetAtEndCommand(element);
            if (atEnd != null)
            {
                atEnd.Execute(null);
            }                   
        }
    });
}
```